# Amazon Linux Breakin Attempt

Tags: linux, security, amazon-ec2

I was having a look in /var/log/secure and noticed the following:

```
Dec  9 06:03:20 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3794]: Did not receive identification string from 177.99.169.130
Dec  9 06:46:12 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3897]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for grupoazul130.static.host.gvt.net.br [177.99.169.130] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Dec  9 06:46:12 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3897]: Invalid user admin from 177.99.169.130
Dec  9 06:46:12 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3897]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Dec  9 06:46:13 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3897]: Received disconnect from 177.99.169.130: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Dec  9 06:46:14 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3899]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for grupoazul130.static.host.gvt.net.br [177.99.169.130] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Dec  9 06:46:15 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3899]: Received disconnect from 177.99.169.130: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Dec  9 06:46:16 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3901]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for grupoazul130.static.host.gvt.net.br [177.99.169.130] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Dec  9 06:46:16 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3901]: Invalid user user from 177.99.169.130
Dec  9 06:46:16 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3901]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
Dec  9 06:46:17 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3901]: Received disconnect from 177.99.169.130: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Dec  9 06:46:19 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3903]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for grupoazul130.static.host.gvt.net.br [177.99.169.130] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Dec  9 06:46:19 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3903]: Invalid user guest from 177.99.169.130
Dec  9 06:46:19 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3903]: input_userauth_request: invalid user guest [preauth]
Dec  9 06:46:19 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3903]: Received disconnect from 177.99.169.130: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Dec  9 06:46:21 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3905]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for grupoazul130.static.host.gvt.net.br [177.99.169.130] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Dec  9 06:46:21 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3905]: Received disconnect from 177.99.169.130: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Dec  9 06:46:23 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3907]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for grupoazul130.static.host.gvt.net.br [177.99.169.130] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Dec  9 06:46:23 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3907]: Invalid user xbian from 177.99.169.130
Dec  9 06:46:23 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3907]: input_userauth_request: invalid user xbian [preauth]
Dec  9 06:46:23 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3907]: Received disconnect from 177.99.169.130: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Dec  9 06:46:25 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3909]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for grupoazul130.static.host.gvt.net.br [177.99.169.130] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Dec  9 06:46:25 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3909]: Invalid user D-Link from 177.99.169.130
Dec  9 06:46:25 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3909]: input_userauth_request: invalid user D-Link [preauth]
Dec  9 06:46:25 ip-10-58-218-177 sshd[3909]: Received disconnect from 177.99.169.130: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
```

What does this mean and should I be worried?

Comment: Welcome to the internet my friend... you didn't think the viagra salesmen just knocked on the email doors, did you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats that the usual random scans trying to find default usernames and passwords. It USUALLY would not be an issue, but if you're worried, [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org), configured properly should take the teeth out of brute force attempts. The default ssh rules should be good enough.